# Unknown keys in an multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I use the following code to retrieve the first key in the first element of the first elelement of the first element of the first element of the first element of an array

`$value = key(reset(reset(reset(reset(($array))))))`

Is there a more beautiful way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Recursion!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

```
function firstKeyOfDeepestArray($array) {
    $a = reset($array);
    if (is_array($a)) {
        return firstKeyOfDeepestArray($a);
    } else {
        return key($array);
    }
}
$value = firstKeyOfDeepestArray($array);
```

Comment: Recursion is certainly the way to go!